# Is there any point to my being able to see the review link here on Meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review

On the non-meta sites, the **review** link becomes available once rep passes 125.  First Posts and Late Answers become accessible for my consideration.  Here on Meta, my rep has passed 125 and all I can see is review categories requiring 2k rep or more.  Is this here to taunt me, egg me on to gain 2K meta rep or is it just an oversight?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first thing the team put there as a "look what you can access someday!"

Comment: `Is this here to taunt me` Yes, that's exactly what Meta is for, all of it, not just /review ;)

Comment: Well, it taunted me into asking the first question I've asked on any SO site.  Quite what that says about me, I don't know.

Comment: Just curious, since you've never been an asker before, how'd you get involved in SE? Did you have a question, but got the answer before having to ask it yourself?

Comment: Found an answer, then found loads of questions **I** could answer.  Particularly wrt Scheme ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just changed this: as of now, on meta sites, the "review" link in the top nav is only visible if you have >= 2k rep.