# To review or not to review, that is the question (aka review link appears even though I can't review anything)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, area-51

On [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), I got a "Review" link next to my username.

I [clicked](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/review) on it, just to discover I couldn't review anything: (as you can see in the screenshot, the minimum reputation to review anything is 2k, while I have 600)

> [image: none]

I can't see any reason why I should have the link when I can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent design change the UI for the top bar is changed, and there is no review option available for the users who have less than 2k reputation.

Screenshot from Area 51 Discussion Zone:

> [image: Area 51 Discussion Zone:]

Answer (score 1):

It shows up because Area 51 Discussions acts basically like a regular Meta site, with the exception of required tags. If you go to a site where you have 500 reputation, you'll see that you can review First Posts and Late Answers. Now, if you head to the Meta site of that site, you'll still see the review link - but you won't be able to review anything, so everything appears grayed out. So on Area 51, the privilege thresholds are the same - so you start to see the review link there, but you can only *really* start reviewing at 3k. (*Not* 2k - no regular suggested edits on Meta sites, and you can only review tag wiki edits at 5k.)

Answer (score 0):

The review link is there by design - to raise awareness of the feature. It makes more sense on regular Q&A sites, that's true, but it still serves a similar purpose on A51 Discuss.

Comment: You might want to delete this answer... the answer bit to it is answering the unfixed question, and the rest of it is requesting clarification (you have the comment privilege ;)).

Comment: @hichris123 Nah, just needed a bit of an edit since the question got edited as well.

Comment: So if this is true, then does the review link show up on meta even if there's no queues that the user can access?

Comment: Answer: [apparently not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151896/237685). I wouldn't say this is for visibility, this is just because Area 51 is too low priority to fix something like this.

Comment: @hichris123 So, the issue here is that MSE is special. It's the only meta site with the Access Review Queues privilege set at 2000 rep. Every other child meta (including A51 Discuss) is at 500. MSE was bumped to 2000 in 2014, a good 2 years after Emmett's answer, so I have a suspicious that at some point we broke the threshold and only sort of put it back. Since it's now been 2 years since *that*, I'll run this by the cogro team to see which way they'd prefer to go here.

Answer (score -3):

This is normal and intended behavior.

Try going to any SE site where you don't have enough points; or to an SE site while not logged on to the network, and select the /review page. You'll see the same.

I'm not sure why the review page is visible to users who don't have enough points to review, but it doesn't hurt, either. My best guess is that SE makes it visible to whet your appetite. That would also explain why you get the "review" link when you're logged in, even though you haven't earned the privilege yet.

Comment: This isn't the problem either; the problem is that the review link is showing up when there's no queue that this user can review in. They're not talking about being able to go to /review, they're talking about a link showing up for /review.