# To vote or not to vote, that is the question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, posts

Many times I have seen people ask for views on good questions and answer. Especially since Winter Bash 2016 has started, I see people requesting for views on good posts, sometimes even asking for upvotes. I think that's good, sharing good posts in a community, but my understanding was that I shouldn't vote on things that you don't stumble upon independently or posts that ask for upvotes, so I have a few questions.

- Is asking for views on a post and maybe implying upvotes ethical? Should it be discouraged?
- Should I upvote these posts I don't stumble upon independently? Downvote?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283434/to-review-or-not-to-review-that-is-the-question-aka-review-link-appears-even-t)

Comment: If someone asks for upvotes in a comment, flag the comment as "not constructive". If they systematically ask for upvotes, edit it out and/or flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Good question. ...........................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvotes are used for good, high-quality posts.

This includes questions and answers that you stumbled upon. There is no rule on how you got to that post; as long you feel that the post deserves the upvote, give it! But don't be pressured neverless, upvotes are not given out freely, they are earned.

> Is asking for views on a post and maybe implying upvotes ethical? Should it be discouraged?

Naturally even if someone asks for upvotes, it should be ignored. The power to upvote stays with all that have the privilege and we are entitled to refuse to upvote the post, even downvote it if necessary. Asking for views seems weird since you probably already on the post which makes no sense...

If one does requests for upvotes, just leave a comment saying that upvotes have to be earned, not given because you want them. Every other user worked hard to make good posts to get those upvotes.

> Should I upvote these posts I don't stumble upon independently? Downvote?

Posts are posts regardless how you reached them and their quality will stay the same (edits may change but that's something different). Downvotes are only to be used if you feel that the post is low-quality. And stumbling upon a post doesn't magically make the post low-quality by itself.

Anyways, whoever or whatever told you that you don't ever upvote on posts you stumble upon is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, good posts should be UVed regardless of how you found them.

If you "stumble upon" a post by yourself, and it is a good post, UV it.
If you search for something and google brings you to a good post, UV it.
If someone points out a good post to you, and it deserves an UV, by all means UV it!

The Stack Exchange votes system is designed so that good posts rise to the top. It has nothing do do with how a user found the post.

If you click on a link posted by another user to a good post that deserves an UV, but you don't UV it because you didn't "stumble upon it," your actually doing a disservice to SE's voting system.

**However, this only applies to good posts.** Posts that do not deserve an UV should *not* be given one. Posts that are not good enough for an UV should not be voted on, unless they are bad enough to deserve a DV...

Answer (score 1):

If someone is asking for votes, or even linking to a post in a place that will get a lot of voting traffic with particular trends (e.g. Meta), consider using more discretion to make sure your votes are well-informed and minimally affected by priming bias.

If you're finding posts *by looking through someone's profile*, as sometimes happens, this is a very risky endeavor; usually you'll be biased one way or another and your votes won't be very good. Avoid unless you can be sure you're not serial voting, not even less than what the reversal script will catch.

Otherwise, it doesn't much matter how you found the post. Just vote on whether it's good or bad as best you can judge.

On the other hand, anyone asking for votes (up, down, close, delete, reopen, undelete, whatever) should, to be ethical, make sure they're asking for *good judgement* and not *a particular degree of favor shown* toward the post. The understanding in rooms like SO's Close Vote Reviewers (which very frequently ask for votes on a post) is that everyone will evaluate posts themselves, rather than trusting others' judgements to be correct.